# How can we allow internal users to access health endpoints in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

We want to secure spring-boot actuator endpoints inside aws. Requirement is not to use spring boot application.yml properties provided by spring boot and secure them using just aws and vpc an/or loadbalancer configuration. And then How can we allow internal users to access those endpoints who're coming from vpn?

For example /actuator/* endpoints

Comment: you may attach a security group to the load-balancer allowing only the clients from the internal network

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it´s what you are looking for but you can use an Application Load Balancer in AWS to allow / deny IPs to certain URLs on your application

https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/aws/new-advanced-request-routing-for-aws-application-load-balancers/